# How to write a mathematical expression in correct way?

Tags: overleaf

I'm using the following code to typeset a mathematical expression but I am not able to get what I want; can someone point my mistake?

```
\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{K}(f_j,f_l) = \frac{exp(-\frac{{||f_j-f_l||}^2}{2\alpha^2})}{\sum_{l^'\in N_j}^{}     exp(-\frac{{||f_j-f_l||}^2}{2\alpha^2})}  \hspace{4mm} l\in N_j
\end{equation}
```

With the above code, I am getting the following expression:[image]

But I want to write it as follows:

[image]

How can I make it correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several changes were needed `\exp` instead of `exp` provides a function instead of 3 variables.  Also, you had an error using `^'`, when you should just use `'`, as the prime already imples the superscript.  I also removed cases of `^{}`.

It was also suggested to use `\lVert` or `\rVert` instead of `||`.  Finally, I used `\bigl(` to change slightly the size of the parens.

Finally, as David noted, `\sigma`, not `\alpha`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \mathcal{K}(f_j,f_l) = \frac{\exp\bigl(-\frac{\lVert f_j-f_l
  \rVert^2}{2\sigma^2}\bigr)}
  {\sum_{l'\in N_j}     
  \exp\bigl(-\frac{\lVert f_j-f_l\rVert^2}{2\sigma^2}\bigr)}  
  \hspace{4mm} l\in N_j
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: and `\sigma` not `\alpha`  to get a sigma

Comment: Also  from the "wanted" picture it appears to be a `\kappa` not `\mathcal{K}`

Answer (score 7):

The “k” is a Greek `\kappa`, not `\mathcal{K}`. You also need `\bm` for the boldface variables and `\exp`, not `exp`. Also `\alpha` should be `\sigma` and `^{'}` should be just `'`.

Using `||` is wrong and it should be `\lVert` and `\rVert`. The last `N` should be `\mathcal{N}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \kappa(\bm{f}_j,\bm{f}_l) =
    \frac{\exp\bigl(-\frac{\lVert \bm{f}_j-\bm{f}_l\rVert^2}{2\sigma^2}\bigr)}
         {\sum_{l'\in N_j}\exp\bigl(-\frac{\lVert \bm{f}_j-\bm{f}_{l'}\rVert^2}{2\sigma^2}\bigr)}  
  ,\quad l\in \mathcal{N}_j
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative answer, which uses inline-fraction notation for the numerator and denominator expressions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{bm}  % for \bm macro
\newcommand\bff{\bm{f}}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \DeclarePairedDelimiter and \mathclap macros
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\kappa(\bff_j,\bff_l) 
= \frac{\exp\bigl(-\norm{\bff_j-\bff_l}^2/(2\sigma^2)\bigr)}{%
\sum\limits_{\mathclap{l'\in N_j}}
\exp\bigl(-\norm{\bff_j-\bff_l}^2/(2\sigma^2)\bigr)}\,,  
\qquad l\in N_j
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```